# How to duplicate numbers in string n times?

Tags: python

I have this string `(61,62,63,64)` and i want to tranform the string into `(61,61,62,62,62,62,63,64)`.

I want to duplicate the numbers in the string n times, the 61 i want to duplicate twice, the 62 i want to duplicate four times, how do i code something that duplicates a number in the string n times?

Can you possible do something like have annother string that tells the computer how many times to duplicate each number? `(61, 62, 63, 64,) (2,4,1,1)`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: What you've described is definitely possible, but Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Try to find a solution on your own first, then ask about specific problems that you encounter.

Comment: will your input be 2 strings with data separated by ',' ?? Please elaborate?

Comment: @ggorlen: "I have this *string*..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution (if `rep` is a string and not a tuple, you just need to do `rep = eval(rep)`):

```
s = "(61,62,63,64)"
rep = (2,4,1,1)

# convert the string to a tuple
t = eval(s)
# compute the result as a tuple
result = tuple(x for i, x in enumerate(t) for _ in range(rep[i]))
# convert the result into a string
result = str(result)
```

If you want something more compact:

```
s = "(61,62,63,64)"
rep = (2,4,1,1)

result = str(tuple(x for i, x in enumerate(eval(s)) for _ in range(rep[i])))
```

Be careful with using `eval`!! Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

if both your inputs are strings:

```
a = '(61, 62, 63, 64,)'
b = '(2,4,1,1)'

a = [i for i in a[1:-1].strip().replace(" ","").split(",")]
a.remove('')
b = [int(i) for i in b[1:-1].strip().replace(" ","").split(",")]
result = "("
for i in range(len(b)):
    for j in  range(b[i]):
        result += a[i]
        result += ", "
result = result.strip()[:-1]+")"
print(result)
```